# Sumproduct multiples of the same lookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 data sets. First, a master table that displays and sums all of the information from the reference tables. The master table looks like this.

```
BayNum     NumCompleted
102
103
104
105
```

The reference table is a running timeline with indicator variables for whether or not something was completed at various time intervals.

```
BayNum    1030    1100    1130    1200    1230
102       1       0       1       0       0
102       0       0       1       0       1
102       1       0       0       1       0
102       0       0       0       0       1
103       0       1       1       1       0
103       1       0       0       0       1
103       1       0       1       1       1
104       1       0       0       0       1
104       0       0       1       0       1
104       1       0       0       1       0
104       1       0       0       0       1
104       1       0       0       0       1
105       1       0       1       0       0
105       0       1       1       1       0
105       0       0       0       0       1
```

I would like the NumCompleted column in the master table to sum all all of the records that have the same bay number.

I think that there is some sort of sumproduct way to go about this but I don't understand arrays very well so I am having trouble visualizing how this works in my head.

I tried this formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT(INDEX(TPH!H2:NC166,MATCH('Post Observations'!$G$2,TPH!$F$2:$F$166,0)))
```

But this returns a reference error I think because Index can only work through a column instead of a full array or something. Would I have to instead do something with Index Small so that it runs through the full list of things? I've done something like that before but I don't know if that would apply here.

Per the example above, I would expect my master table to look like this.

```
BayNum     NumCompleted
102        7
103        9
104        10
105        6
```

Comment: I assume your example result for BayNum 103 is a typo and should actually be 9?

Comment: Yes that's correct. Ill fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT` to multiply each cell in the range, by whether the "BayNum" matches (1 if it does or 0 if not), then sum all the results:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$F$8)*($A$2:$A$8=$H2))
```

[image]